# Delete duplicate site names, ignoring http protocol and www

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Spreadsheet Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry4Q8.png)

I have this sheet and I want to delete duplicate values on each row, I know they're not duplicate in the essence that some has http:// and others have www. But I want to delete duplicate link even they have application protocol.

I have a sample code that I used

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Can someone help me to disregard the reading of http:// and www. on the link and delete the rows with a same values even they have application protocol in there links.

Comment: Why the Excel tag?

Comment: to make a good question, do try to make the change and show us what went wrong. asking us to modify code you found is not a proper question for this forum. Remember the forum is for programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the duplication is determined just by one column (A), the logic can be simplified. Keep an array of already-seen sites with their URLs brought to a standard form: no protocol, no www, lower case, no trailing/leading spaces.  This transformation is done below with

```
data[i][0].replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/, "").toLowerCase().trim();
```

The function checks whether the truncated form of a new site matches the records; if it does not, the row is kept as a new one, otherwise ignored.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  var truncatedData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var truncatedSite = data[i][0].replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/, "").toLowerCase().trim();
    if (truncatedData.indexOf(truncatedSite) == -1) {
      newData.push(data[i]);
      truncatedData.push(truncatedSite)
    }
  }
  if (newData.length < data.length) {
    sheet.clearContents();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @soup that work great ! is there a way that whenever i post duplicate link it will automatically run the function ? right now i have to run it via google script editor of the spreadsheet.

Comment: If you rename the function to `onEdit`, it will run with every edit. May slow things down a bit, though.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the script just now so that it does not rewrite the sheet when there are no changes to make.

Comment: The com part would be at the end, so you may want to do a separate replace for it, `.replace(/\.com\/?$/, "")`

Comment: yeah i already think of it before you posted your comment thanks anyway hehe.